# photo not displaying after making php call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to retrieve some data from a database using php, then I add the data inside json_encode array to be sent to my other php file so that the contents could be displayed on a site.  currently I am able to retrieve contents that contain text however, I am unable to retrieve the images. For example instead of displaying an image of London, the text London..jpg is displayed.

Here is my php file that selects the data for the data base

```
         <?php
require_once('conn.inc.php'); 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT CityName,CityID, CityPopulation,CitySkills,CityEmploymentRates,CityjsaClaimants ,Image ,CityWeeklyEarnings FROM citiesdata WHERE CityID = ? ORDER BY CityName");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['CityID']);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($CityName, $CityID,$CityPopulation,$CitySkills,$CityEmploymentRates,$CityjsaClaimants,$Image,$CityWeeklyEarnings); 
$myArray = array();

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $myArray[] = $CityName;

    $myArray[] = $CityPopulation;
    $myArray[] = $CitySkills;
    $myArray[] = $CityEmploymentRates;
    $myArray[] = $CityjsaClaimants;
    $myArray[] = $Image;
    $myArray[] = $CityWeeklyEarnings;


}
echo json_encode($myArray);


?>
```

And here is the javascript code I am using to retrieve the data in to my website, I am retrieving the data using CityID for example if CityID is 1 a radio button is clicked with value 1 this will match the CityID of 1 which is London and the details of the city will be displayed except the image since I have multiple images I have used json_encode I have no idea where to put the image src since I am working with multiple cities with multiple images. Everything is displayed fine on the website the cityName,Cityskills etc when the user selects a city via a radio button, how can I make it so that when the user selects the radio button the city images will be displayed alongside the cityNames, city skills etc?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name=CityID]').on('click', function(){
var sendVals = $(this).serialize();
        var returnData = "";
        $("#displayResults").html('<li>Please Wait!</li>');
        $.get("phpCalling.php", sendVals, function(myData){

            $.each(myData, function(key, value) {

                returnData += "<p>"
                returnData += value;
                returnData += "</p>";
            })
            $("#displayResults").html(returnData);

        }, "json");

    });

});
```

Comment: Aren't you just outputting the link with your method? It needs to be added as an image `<img src='var should be here'>`

Comment: How are you storing the image in the database? Are you storing the image itself as a `blob` or just its filepath?

Comment: @JoshBalcitis, I am storing the Image as London.jpg without the filepath

Comment: @Sky you aren't storing the image, you are storing a **link** to the image... Like I said in my first comment, you'll need to create an image with this link.

Comment: shouldn't you be doing value.image or something like that? along with <img> tags with relative path

Comment: if you're just storing the text `london.jpg` in the db, then you'll have to output an appropriate image tag and url for that filename, e.g. `<img src="/path/to/london.jpg" />`. because, otherwise, what you're doing is the equivalent of writing "ferrari" on some scrap paper and wondering why you don't get a supercar in your driveway.

Comment: @MarcB I only need to draw a picture and wrap image tags around it to get a real ferrari? Didn't realize that was my problem! :P

Comment: But I am trying to send multiple images from the database which in turn is sent via json

Comment: Solved my problem ohhh  i feel like a loser it was simple!

Answer (score 0):

change your following code

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$myArray[] = $CityName;

$myArray[] = $CityPopulation;
$myArray[] = $CitySkills;
$myArray[] = $CityEmploymentRates;
$myArray[] = $CityjsaClaimants;
$myArray[] = $Image;
$myArray[] = $CityWeeklyEarnings;


}
```

as

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$myArray[] = $CityName;

$myArray[] = $CityPopulation;
$myArray[] = $CitySkills;
$myArray[] = $CityEmploymentRates;
$myArray[] = $CityjsaClaimants;
$myArray[] = '<img src="'.$Image.'"/>';
$myArray[] = $CityWeeklyEarnings;
```

}